# Remove file from choosen files in preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I got a site where the user can upload multiple files (images only). I added a function where the uploaded files can be seen in a preview. I got help from an other post on stackoverflow.

```js
function previewImages() {

    var $preview = $('#preview').empty();
    if (this.files) $.each(this.files, readAndPreview);
  
    function readAndPreview(i, file) {
      
      if (!/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name)){
        return alert(file.name +" is not an image");
      }
      
      var reader = new FileReader();
  
      $(reader).on("load", function() {
        $preview.append($("<img/>", {src:this.result, height:100}));
      });
  
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      
    }
  
  }
  
  $('#file-input').on("change", previewImages);
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
        <label class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm">
            <i class="mdi mdi-upload"></i>
            <span class="position-relative" style="top: -2px;">Upload image</span>
            <input type="file" style="display: none;" id="file-input" multiple>
        </label>
        <div id="preview" class="my-3"></div>
    </div>
```

Now I want to make a functionality for each uploaded image there should be a remove button (below the image). If the user **clicks on remove, the associated image is removed** and no longer displayed.
I currently have no idea how to do that. Do someone know a answer to my question?

I used the libaray Dropzone but it was buggy so I decided to not work with this no more.

Comment: Please try https://www.dropzonejs.com/bootstrap.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap your `img` tag with a parent section and add an element for removing that image. Then, add a click listener to that element and remove respective image easily like this:

```js
function previewImages() {

    var $preview = $('#preview').empty();
    if (this.files) $.each(this.files, readAndPreview);

    function readAndPreview(i, file) {

        if (!/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name)) {
            return alert(file.name + " is not an image");
        }

        var reader = new FileReader();

        $(reader).on("load", function (e) {
            $preview.append(`<span class="parent-span">
                <img class="imageThumb" src="`+ e.target.result + `" title="` + file.name + `"/>
                <br/><span class="remove">Remove image</span>
                </span>`);
        });

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

        $(document).on("click", ".remove", function () {
            $(this).parent(".parent-span").remove();
        });

    }

}

$('#file-input').on("change", previewImages);
```

```css
.imageThumb {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.parent-span {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.remove {
    background: #444;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.remove:hover {
    background: white;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <label class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm">
        <i class="mdi mdi-upload"></i>
        <span class="position-relative" style="top: -2px;">Upload image</span>
        <input type="file" style="display: none;" id="file-input" multiple>
    </label>
    <div id="preview" class="my-3"></div>
</div>
```